# max width tag not working with IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am using the following code snippet in my CSS:

```
img {  
  /* Responsive images (ensure images don't scale beyond their parents) */

  max-width: 100%;
  /* Part 1: Set a maxium relative to the parent */

  width: auto\9;
  /* IE7-8 need help adjusting responsive images */

  height: auto;
  /* Part 2: Scale the height according to the width, otherwise you get stretching */

  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 0;
  -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}
```

However, the `max-width` does not work with IE and the image enlarges. any fix/solutions?

Comment: `width: auto; height: auto` are the defaults anyway, so no need to include them. (And did you mean to have `\9` in there?) The max-width should work, unless you are talking about a very older version of IE that is obsolete.

Comment: What version of IE are you using? If it's a recent version, have you checked that you're in standards mode, not quirks mode?

Comment: @ralph.m: `auto` is needed if the HTML img tag has (or might have) HTML attributes for the `width` and `height`. `auto` overrides the HTML attributes.

Comment: @Eashwar: Do you want the image to always fill 100% of the width of the parent element? Or do you want the image to have its normal size, but prevent it from being larger than the width of the parent element? Also, providing a demo would help.

Comment: Checkout this solution it may have the problem could have the same origin: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18075165/ie5-max-width-support-posible-solution/18075772#18075772

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
width: inherit;
```

Should fix any IE problems.

Comment: "Any IE problems" is a bit far-fetched ;) I think this solves a problem for IE8 Browser Mode.