# IE5 max-width support & posible solution

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-5

I simply wanna set a max and a min width to my content in my IE5 compatible site i read out of **[this](http://perishablepress.com/maximum-and-minimum-height-and-width-in-internet-explorer/)** site that the solution below could solve it, in this following example i only show max width.

But there must be some issue cause it don't work can somebody tell me what is wrong? or another solution - it can have a javascript solution - but i need to be IE5 supported?

```
* html .wrapper { 
   width: expression( document.body.clientWidth > 960 ? "961px" : "auto" ); /* sets max-width for IE */
}
html .wrapper{
  max-width: 960px;
}
```

- A footnote i compile it with compass cause its a s Sass project (it dosn't fail in the build step)

Comment: ***IE5?!?!??*** Not even 5.5?

Comment: yes ie5 - it need to be ran trough some oldtimer programs which our client uses - IE5.5 might solve it

Comment: This may be an exception to the rule that the client is always right. :-)

Comment: Im searching for answer not comments about its stupid to use IE5 - tough i totally agree with you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If found out what made it bug

it seems that IE5 for some odd reason ignore the expression if your normal statement isn't width and not max-width see solution below

```
* html .wrapper { 
   width: expression( document.body.clientWidth > 960 ? "961px" : "auto" ); /* sets max-width for IE */
}
html .wrapper{
  width: 960px;
}
html.gtie7 .wrapper{
  max-width: 960px;
  width: auto;
}
```

hope it was useful if anybody some day should run into the same problem